# How to make a heat map on top of worldmap using hist3 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

My x-axis is latitudes, y-axis is longitudes, and z-axis is the `hist3` of the two. It is given by: `z=hist3(location(:,1:2),[180,360])`, where `location(:,1)` is the latitude column, and `location(:,2)` is the longitude column.

What I now want is, instead of plotting on a self-created XY plane, I want to plot the same on a worldmap. And instead of representing the frequency of each latitude-longitude pair with the height of the bars of `hist3`, I want to represent the frequency of each location by a heat map on top of the world map, corresponding to each latitude-longitude pair's frequency on the dataset. I have been searching a lot for this, but have not found much help. How to do this? I could only plot the skeleton of the worldmap like this:

```
worldmap world
load geoid
geoshow(geoid, geoidrefvec, 'DisplayType', 'texturemap');
load coast
geoshow(lat, long)
```

I don't know what the colour is being produced based on.

Additionally, if possible, I would also like to know how to plot the `hist3` on a 3D map of the world (or globe), where each bar of the `hist3` would correspond to the frequency of each location (i.e., each latitude-longitude pair). Thank you.

Comment: You have the values in Z for every (x,y) of the map. Just change the intensity of every found pixel of the map with the value in Z and that should do it. Then use colormap to give different values to the point of the map.

Comment: That's what. How to do that? I don't know the syntax. I searched a lot, and whatever I tried always throws some error.

Comment: If your map is a matrix with dimensions M and N, than it's easy.

For i=1:M
For j=1:N
New_Map(i,j)= Z(Map(i,j))
end
end

If Map(i,j) equals 200, for example, than the histogram on position 200 yields the value that needs to be added to the position i,j of the Map, or with other words Z(200), which generally speaking is Z(Map(i,j)). You loop this for all the values of i and j and in that way you change every pixel of the map in the newly created map.

More about the colormap can be found here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html

Comment: That's not what I want though. I basically want, in other words, that my `hist3` graph, should be superimposed on top of the world map. But while doing so, if we look at the bars of the histogram from top view, their height is not visible, right? So, I want that the bars be replaced by colors, and their intensity should be proportional to the heights of the bars. I want the map to be like this: http://www.outline-world-map.com/map-images-original/blank-transparent-thick-world-map-b1c.png. And I want bars to be replaced by colors with the exact same proportional intensity as the height of bars.

Comment: Even now I saw that it's about hist3 and not hist, or imhist. I'm sorry about that. I will convert my comment into an answer, it's getting a bit lengthy and I wanna use code lines.

Answer (score 1):

The hist3 documentation, which you can find here [hist3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html), says:
*Color the bars based on the frequency of the observations, i.e. according to the height of the bars.* `set(get(gca,'child'),'FaceColor','interp','CDataMode','auto');`

If that's not what you need, you might wanna try it with colormap. More info about it here [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html). I haven't tried using colormap on histograms directly, so If colormap doesn't help, then you can try creating a new matrix manually which will have values in colors instead of the Z values the histogram originally had.

To do that, you need to first calculate the maximum Z value with:

```
maxZ=max(Z);
```

Then, you need to calculate how much of the colors should overlap. For example, if you use RGB system and you assign Blue for the lowest values of the histogram, then Green for the middle and Red for the High, and the green starts after the Blue with no overlap, than it will look artificial. So, if you decide that you will have, for example overlapping of 10 values, than, having in mind that every R, G and B component of the RGB color images have 255 values (8 bits) and 10 of each overlap with the former, that means that you will have 255 values (from the Blue) + 245 values (From the Green, which is 255 - 10 since 10 of the Green overlap with those of the Blue) + 245 (From the Red, with the same comment as for the Green), which is total amount of 745 values that you can assign to the new colored Histogram.

If `745 > maxZ` there is no logic for you to map the new Z with more than maxZ values. Then you can calculate the number of overlaping values in this manner:

```
if 745 > maxZ
    overlap=floor(255- (maxZ-255)/2)
end
```

At this point you have 10 overlapping values (or more if you still think that it doesn't looks good) if the maximum value of the Z is bigger than the total amount of values you are trying to assign to the new Z, or `overlap` overlapping values, if the maximum of Z is smaller.

When you have this two numbers (i.e. 745 and maxZ), you can write the following code so you can create the newZ.

First you need to specify that newZ is of the same size as Z. You can achieve that by creating a zero matrix with the same size as Z, but having in mind that in order to be in color, it has to have an additional dimension, which will specify the three color components (if you are working with RGB).

This can be achieved in the following manner:

```
newZ=zeros(size(Z),3)
```

The number 3 is here, as I said, so you would be able to give color to the new histogram.

Now you need to calculate the step (this is needed only if maxZ > The number of colors you wish to assign). The step can be calculated as:

```
stepZ=maxZ/Total_Number_of_Colors
```

If maxZ is, for example 2000 and Total_Number_of_Colors is (With 10 overlaping colours) 745, then stepZ=2.6845637583892617449664429530201. You will also need a counter so you would know what color you would assign to the new matrix. You can initialize it here:

```
count=0;
```

Now, finally the assignment is as follows:

```
For i=1:stepZ:maxZ
count=count+1;
If count>245
   NewZ(Z==stepz,3)=count;
elseif count>245 && count<256
   NewZ(Z==stepz,3)=count;
   NewZ(Z==stepz,2)=count-245;
elseif count>255
   NewZ(Z==stepz,2)=count-245;
elseif count>500 && count<511
   NewZ(Z==stepz,2)=count-245;
   NewZ(Z==stepz,1)=count-500;
else
   NewZ(Z==stepz,1)=count-500;
end
end
```

At this point you have colored your histogram. Note that you can manually color it in different colors than red, green and blue (even if you are working in RGB), but it would be a bit harder, so if you don't like the colors you can experiment with the last bit of code (the one with the `for` loops), or check the internet of some other automatic way to color your `newZ` matrix.

Now, how do you think to superimpose this matrix (histogram) over your map? Do you want only the black lines to be shown over the colored histogram? If that's the case, than it can be achieved by resampling the NewZ matrix (the colored histogram) with the same precision as the map. For example, if the map is of size MxN, then the histogram needs to be adjusted to that size. If, on the other hand, their sizes are the same, then you can directly continue to the next part.

Your job is to find all pixels that have black in the map. Since the map is not binary (blacks and whites), it will be a bit more harder, but still achievable. You need to find a satisfactory threshold for the three components. All the lines under this threshold should be the black lines that are shown on the map. You can test these values with `imshow(worldmap)` and checking the values of the black lines you wish to preserve (borders and land edges, for example) by pointing the cross tool on the top of the figure, in the tools bar on every pixel which is of interest.

You don't need to test *all* black lines that you wish to preserve. You just need to have some basic info about what values the threshold should have. Then you continue with the rest of the code and if you don't like the result so much, you just adjust the threshold in some trial and error manner. When you have figured that this threshold is, for example, (40, 30, 60) for all of the RGB values of the map that you wish to preserve (have in mind that only values that are between (0,0,0) and (40,30,60) will be kept this way, all others will be erased), then you can add the black lines with the following few commands:

```
for i = 1:size(worldmap,1)
for j = 1:size(worldmap,2)
    if worldmap(i,j,1)<40 && worldmap(i,j,2)<30 && worldmap(i,j,3)<60
       newZ(i,j,:)=worldmap(i,j,:)
    end
end
```

I want to note that I haven't tested this code, since I don't have Matlab near me atm, so It can have few errors, but those should be easily debugable.

Hopes this is what you need,
Cheers!